# Changing value of a specific object in array of objects - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, game-development

Hi guys I am trying to create a board game using React and function components so I use hooks.

I've got an array of around 30 objects representing fields of the board:

```
[...,{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Berlin",
    "country": "Germany",
    "price": 2500,
    "floorPrice": 500,
    "buildingPrice": 1500,
    "baseFee": 300,
    "maxFee": 2000,
    "pawns": [],
    "type": "city",
    "owner": {}
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Warsaw",
    "country": "Poland",
    "price": 2400,
    "floorPrice": 400,
    "buildingPrice": 1200,
    "baseFee": 250,
    "maxFee": 1800,
    "pawns": [],
    "type": "city",
    "owner": {}
},...]
```

When pawn steps on a specific field it can buy a property from this field just like in monopoly, by adding pawn as an owner in object. It works but when I try to buy another property/field then the last property I bought before this one lost it's owner.

This is my code for modifying copy of my array from json:

```
  setAllFields(
    allFields.map(item => (
      {...item, owner: (item.id !== playerOne.position ? item.owner : (item.owner = {'owner': 'playerOne'}))}
    ))
  );
```

I Would really appreciate any sugestions :)

```js
let allFields = [];

const myFieldsArr = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Wroclaw",
        "pawns": ['playerOne'],
        "owner": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Warsaw",
        "pawns": ['playerTwo'],
        "owner": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Lodz",
        "pawns": [],
        "owner": []
    }
]

allFields = myFieldsArr.map(field => (
  {...field, owner: (field.id === 1 ? (field.owner =['playerOne']) : field.owner)}
))

console.log(allFields)


allFields = myFieldsArr.map(field => (
  {...field, owner: (field.id === 2 ? (field.owner =['playerTwo']) : field.owner)}
))


console.log(allFields)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: owner is an object. What are the key and values supposed to be?

Comment: "owner": {'owner': 'playerOne'} because later on I will ad there more data that's why there is an object

Comment: will all the keys inside the root owner object be "owner"? in that case just use an array like `"owner": ['playerOne']`

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Why are you doing `item.owner = {'owner': 'playerOne'}` in the false case of the conditional? That's modifying a state object, which you seem to know you're [not supposed to do](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly).

Comment: Ok I changed it to array so "owner": ['playerOne'] although it just changes the structure, problem remains edit(will create snippet)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Valid point, thanks

Comment: Please try to share a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] so we've better context for what the code is doing and when, and where the logic goes awry.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't because I am not the owner, it is commercial and code is put together in a way that it is almost impossible to show only part of it. Thankfully answears I received from you guys gave me some direction. I will post here a solution when I manage to solve this and appreciate every useful answear.

Comment: I don't think anyone said anything about sharing protected code. We asked for a minimal reproducible code example that demonstrates the issue. The goal is to get a working solution that you can take and apply to your code.

Comment: Yeah I understand that but the closest I can get to minimal code example is the snippet i delivered in my question. The thing is when I isolate it like this, it works, as well as Ayudh's answear and this means that the problem is in some other function that is updating state along the way and removing changes I made to my array of obj. And because I can not find it there is no sense in pasting here whole app/game.

Comment: It turns out I needed to modify other function that was overriding my state changes using fetch. Another solution that also worked is to modify player/pawn data instead of field data by creating something like this:
```setPlayerTwo(existingValues => ({...existingValues, portfolio: [...playerTwo.portfolio, {'purchase': playerTwo.position}]}))```

Answer (score 1):

```
setAllFields(
    allFields.map(item => (
      {...item, owner: (item.id !== playerOne.position ? item.owner : ['playerOne']}
    ))
  );
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I tried that but then it even does not add player to owner field.
Strange thing is that it works with snippet I created so it seems the problem is connected to state somehow...